# How to create custom page in woocommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am looking to create a custom page in my Woocommerce plugin which gets linked to when clicking on a certain link. The page is not a templated Woocommerce page.

But I can not get the page to include the header or footer or any content for that matter.

I have the page currently sitting at the root of my plugin directory and I link to it `/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/mypage.php`.

Is there a better way to do this and include the header and footer of the site?

Thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate your question please?

Comment: Let's see if I can do a better job getting my problem across. I am making a woocommerce plugin. Within that plugin I override the default button for single product and rather attach a link to the button. When a user clicks on that button I would like it to open a php page within my plugin. Within that page I want to include the current header and footer. Does that make more sense ?

Comment: You can create your own custom endpoint. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211524/6477)

Comment: @AdrianBegi Were you able to accomplish this? Need something similar